# Is $\textbf{MAN}$ a full subcategory of $\textbf{LRS}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Let **MAN** be the category of differentiable manifolds with smooth maps as morphisms. Let **LRS** be the category of *locally ringed spaces*. Now I know that there exists a functor $\textbf{MAN}\to\textbf{LRS}$ that associates
$$
  M\mapsto(M, C^\infty)
$$

where $ C^\infty$ is the sheaf of smooth functions  on $M$. My question is whether this functor is fully faithfull, that is, given a morphism of locally ringed spaces 
$$
  (M, C^\infty)\to(N, C^\infty)
$$
then is the associated function $M\to N$ smooth? I know that we will have to use that the induced map at stalks is local at some point, but I can't see how.